# All new tabs in PhpStorm will be opened pinned

Tags: phpstorm, settings

Where can I find the setting so that new tabs are not pinned when they are opened?

Comment: Please share some details: what files / how do you work with them. If you can make some screenshots (or better some small video or gif) that would clearly show the process it would give some hints on what is happening/what to look for.

Comment: The problem occurs when I open files from the Remote Host window. Until recently, the tabs weren't pinned directly. But now every tab is pinned directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem occurs when I open files from the Remote Host window.

Sadly this cannot be disabled right now.

That is the known issue and it is already fixed ([WI-55870](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-55870): pinning by default is removed) for the next minor **2020.3.1 version**.

2020.3.1 EAP build should be available later this week for you to try ([watch PhpStorm's blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) for updates) and actual release is expected at some point later this month.

Comment: Many Thanks! Right now that you point it out. The problem only occurred after the update: - /